# Can SQLServer replication be limited to a specific set of tables in a database?

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking at SQLServer replication.   When I replicate, obviously the entire database can be replicated.   However, is it possible to limit the replication to a specific set of tables or schemas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes--this is pretty straight-forward.  Just go into the publish properties of your replication definition and unselect the tables you do not want replicated.